# Hidden file on github?

Tags: git, github

I don't use github often. But recently I ran into such a problem. There is a github repository and it shows that the last update was 2 hours ago, but when switching to the repository itself, the last update was about a month ago. The other two branches of the repository are even older. Github has hidden branches?

main page:

[image]

repo:
[image]

Comment: If this isn't a private repo, would you mind sharing it?

Comment: I think a tag or release could also trigger an update.

Comment: A any kind of push would trigger an update - even a force push, and if that is the case all commit dates could still be unchanged.